# after migrating my code to Laravel 10, I had errors

Tags: laravel

after migrating to 10 i have error

after migrating to 10 i have error

ErrorException: Undefined property: YourModel::$dates
Error: Call to undefined method App\Jobs\YourJob::dispatchNow()
BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Route::home()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For This Error: *ErrorException: Undefined property: YourModel::$dates*

protected `$dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];`
in the model is deprecated change to

`protected $casts = [ 'created_at' => 'datetime', ....];`

For This Error: *BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Route::home()*

`Route::home` method has been  deprecated  use `Route::get('/', '');`

For This Error: *Call to undefined method App\Jobs\YourJob::dispatchNow()*

`$job->dispatchNow(); is now $job->dispatchSync();`

Do Kindly upgrade document for Laravel [click here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/upgrade#main-content)